# Combining conditional statements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I have two variables that hold objects:

```
var person1 = {
  name: "Joe",
  study: false  
 };

var person2 = {
  name: "Tom",
  study: true  
 };
```

I've created two functions such that after a function is called, it will call both of these functions:

```
var person1study = function() {
  if (person1.study === true){
    person.study = false;
  }
  else {
    person1.study = true;
  }
  };

var person2study = function() {
  if (person2.study === true){
    person2.study = false;
  }
  else {
    person2.study = true;
  } 
  };
```

Is there a way that I can combine these who functions into a single function that does that same thing?

Comment: `personx.study = !personx.study;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just declare the object as a parameter:

```
function toggleStudy(person) {
  person.study = !person.study;
}

toggleStudy(person1); // invert the "study" flag on the "person1" object
```

The `!` operator evaluates its operand as a boolean value, and returns the opposite value.

Answer (score 0):

```
var personStudy = function(person) {
  person.study = !person.study;
  };
```

like this?